# How to get the actual grid-row value of a cell?

Tags: jquery, css

`cell` is a jQuery object of for a `div` inside a CSS `grid` layout.

This: `cell.css("grid-row")`

Returns this: `auto / auto`

How can I get the actual numeric row value of the `cell`?

---

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/2/

When you open the console, you can see the output as `auto / auto`. I want `1 / span 1` or `1 / 2` etc. so I can get the first character, in this case, `1`.

Comment: Try to use cell.outerHeight() http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/.

Comment: Would you create a jsfiddle sample to make your question clear? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Deniz Added to the question.

Comment: You are not adding `grid-row` property to cell by yourself. jQuery is returning the default value. If you add `grid-row` to cell, you will get your value. https://jsfiddle.net/4brvo92g/

Comment: You can have it by using height() method and if you have margin/paddings you can use outerHeight() https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/4/ Is not that the answer what you are looking for? If not, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Deniz I am trying to get which row the current cell div is sitting at. For example, it would be 1 for all the cells in the first row, 2 for the second row, 3 for the third row. etc. Technically I can divide total height to outerHeight() and Math.ceil the result to get that value; but that only works if all cells are uniformly sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a dynamic solution for you. Hope it helps

```
$(function(){
    var rowSize =$(".cell").first().css("grid-row").split('/').length
  $(".cell").each((c,elem)=>{
    elem.innerText= Math.ceil(++c / rowSize)
  })
})
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/7/

Comment: now you updated grid row columns so you need to update that rowSize variable for that , you cant expect to work it on every css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/10/ here you go , this is your expected solution i guess and please stop changing the question

Comment: This one works: https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/11/ I am accepting your answer since it was your idea, to begin with. You may want to edit your answer though, in order to help future visitors.

Comment: I did not change the question, though. Version #7 of the Fiddle was incorrect since the 'rowSize' would always equal to 2, no matter what the actual column count is. Because grid-row property is always in the format 'a / b'.  I was trying to demonstrate this issue. The actual column count is given in the grid object itself with grid-template-columns property, which you figured out later as well. That being said, this solution is still not dynamic enough since we cannot guarantee someone won't use repeat function in their grid-template-columns property value.

Answer (score 0):

From the jsfiddle I can see you haven't added any `grid-row` property. that's why you are getting the default `auto / auto`. if you add grid property like `grid-row: 1 / 3;` then it logs `1 / 3` to the console.

Comment: I don't want to add a manual grid-row property. I want it to be auto. I just want to know that automatic-assigned value at the runtime.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is not possible to get the actual value of `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding `grid-row` property to cell by yourself. jQuery is returning the default value. If you add `grid-row` to cell, you will get your value. https://jsfiddle.net/4brvo92g/

Comment: I don't want to add a manual grid-row property. I want it to be auto. I just want to know that automatic-assigned value at the runtime.

Comment: Automatically assigned value is what you are getting `auto / auto`

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, hence the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hardcoding the `grid-area` property with jQuery. This is an ugly solution and requires knowledge about the column count beforehand, therefore it is not dynamic:

```
$(".cell").each(function (index) {
    $(this).text(index); // for debugging

    var col = index % 2; // 2 is the column count, hardcoded.
    var row = Math.floor(index / 2); // ditto

    $(this).css({"grid-area": (row + 1) + " / " + (col + 1) + " / span 1 / span 1"});
});
```

I am not marking this answer as accepted since I imagine a more dynamic approach should be possible.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9gepnLhk/5/